# Tensorflow - Edit a TFRecord

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0, tfrecord

**Question:** Is there a way to append an existing TFRecord?

**Note:** The .TFRecord is created by my own script (not a .tfrecord I found on web), so I have full control of its contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to append to an existing records file as such, or at least not through the functions that TensorFlow provides. Record files are written at C++ level by a [`PyRecordWriter`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.0.0/tensorflow/python/lib/io/py_record_writer.h), which [calls](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.0.0/tensorflow/python/lib/io/py_record_writer.cc#L34) the function [`NewWriteableFile`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.0.0/tensorflow/core/platform/env.h#L100-L114) when it is created, deleting any existing file with the given name to create a new one. However, it is possible to create a new records file with the contents of another one followed by new records.

For TensorFlow 1.x, you could do it like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def append_records_v1(in_file, new_records, out_file):
    with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(out_file) as writer:
        with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session():
            ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([in_file])
            rec = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
            while True:
                try:
                    writer.write(rec.eval())
                except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError: break
        for new_rec in new_records:
            writer.write(new_rec)
```

In TensorFlow 2.x (eager execution), you could do it like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def append_records_v2(in_file, new_records, out_file):
    with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(out_file) as writer:
        ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([in_file])
        for rec in ds:
            writer.write(rec.numpy())
        for new_rec in new_records:
            writer.write(new_rec)
```

Comment: Thank you! Why `r.numpy()` in the TF 2.0 version? Shouldn't it be `rec.numpy()`? Also, about the creating of the new TFRecord with the contents of an existing one, will it take the same time to parse the old contents? If yes, it doesn't help much. I can create it just from scratch, the interesting part is, will it be faster to write the contents from that TFRecord to a new one

Comment: @IlanAizelman Yes, it should be `rec`, sorry, thanks for pointing that out. About speed, it works be a bit faster, since it does not really parse the records, but I don't know if it would make a big difference or not, that depends...

Comment: I see, that makes sense, as I thought too. I'll check this approach soon. Thanks again.